# Integers of the form 89, 889, 8889,... not perfect squares

Tags: number-theory

Show that an integer of the form 89, 889, 8889,... is not a perfect square.

I know a perfect square will have an odd number of divisors so my first attempt would be assuming that an integer of the form 89, 889, 8889,... is a perfect square and then show that 89, 889, 8889,... all have an even number of divisors. I do not know how to begin proving that 89, 889, 8889,... all have an even number of divisors. Any hints or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This might help: $x$ is a square if and only if $9x$ is a square, right? Also, $888,\!889\times9=8,\!000,\!001$.

Comment: More generally, the $n$th number in the sequence can be expressed in the form
$$
8\frac{10^{n+1} - 1}{9} + 1 = \frac 19 \left(8 \cdot 10^{n+1} + 1 \right)
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $8\cdot10^n+1=x^2$ for some $n$.

Then $(x+1)(x-1)=2^{n+3}5^n$

Note that for all $n\geq3$, we have $5^n>2^{n+3}$+2.

Since only one of $x+1,x-1$ can be a multiple of $5$, $5^n$ must divide one of them and we have $x+1\geq5^n$, $x-1\leq2^{n+3}$ or $x-1\geq5^n$, $x+1\leq2^{n+3}$ which are both impossible for $n\geq 3$.

So we need to only check $n=1,2$ and $81=9^2$ while $801$ is not a square.

However $81<89$ so it does not correspond to one of the listed number. So no listed number is a square.